# Vectorworks Installer on Windows 10 not working

Tags: windows, windows-10, installer

I tried to install [Vectorworks for students](https://www.computerworks.ch/software/vectorworks.html) on my Windows 10. I have a `64 bit system` and have the installer on my machine.
When I click the installer a new process shows up in the task manager using little memory and no cpu usage. I tried following things:

- Starting it as admin
- Starting the service msiinstaller (Altough it's an `.exe`)
- Using the `cmd` program to try and start it
- Disable `Windows Defender`
- Adding `.exe` to the installer name
- Starting it in compatibility mode

What else could I try to get it running?

Comment: Have you checked to see if you have a corrupt download?

Comment: Did you mean that when you try all the ways to run it, it still does not happen? Any error you get? Have you tried to run it in the clean boot? It could have conflicts with other programs or services.

Comment: We tried all these things, no error message no visible progress.

Comment: How would I check for a corrupt download? It seems just like a reqular installer.